# How to Replace Entire default Djnago Admin with custom Admin

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-admin

I want to replace the default Django Admin templates with a completely revamped bootstrap version. The data in the Dashboard should be populated from the DB. How do I work with templated files ? Which files should be overriden ? In which template tag does HTML code go ?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/admin/#overriding-admin-templates

Comment: The docs are not very much helpful. How do I fetch data like total number of Users in the platforms, Booking Information from the DB and display on the dashboard. And also edit or make changes in the DB via the Dashboard

Comment: [Total number of objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.count). What's booking information? That's not part of default admin. It seems like creating your own admin would be better for you, instead of replacing existing.

Comment: @Gasanov My project is like an e-commerce website which has all kinds of data about Users, various bookings made by users, transactions completed, payment status and so on. What would be the best approach in this case ? To override Django Admin or to create an independent Admin Website in React/Angular/Vue and make it communicate with Django Backend via REST APIs ? What would be the limitations in terms of security/CSRF token/functionality/difference from default Django Admin/ that would be faced in both of the approaches ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [django docs on admin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/admin/):

> The admin’s recommended use is limited to an organization’s internal management tool. It’s not intended for building your entire front end around.

It's possible to change templates to do what you want, but that will be **very complex** - you have to basically rewrite most of the templates, get to know how it is working internally and probably change that too to your own design (after all, you are going to show specific details, like charts, data and so).

You will faster to achieve results if you going to build your own app, that will work exactly like you need without multiple fixes. Does it have to use js frameworks depends entirely on your requirements. Usually they are much more simple for admin backends, that are going to be used by owners, not clients. Anyway, if you don't have experience or knowledge in this, you will probably better off with just plain static django templates.

Django admin is just a [same app as the ones you build](https://github.com/django/django/tree/master/django/contrib/admin), so limitations will be the same. Security wise, it doesn't offer much that you can't do yourself - make sure you have permissions set in models/views. Read more about [security in django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/security/).
From functionality point of view, django admin just comes with CRUD access to your models, which can be done quite quickly. Once you past that, you will have much easier time adding functionality to your own app instead of overriding django admin.

Overall, I advise you to build your app for CMS-like admin panel. JS frameworks is neat, but that require burden of multiple additional tests (with api mocks), constant swapping between adding api / writing a component and much higher time consumption overall.